# How to suppress logs in tesseract.js

Tags: node.js, tesseract, tesseract.js

When I call `worker.recognize` I get

```
Info in pixReadMemPng: converting (cmap + alpha) ==> RGBA
Info in pixReadMemPng: converting 8 bpp cmap with alpha ==> RGBA
```

logs in console. How can I get rid of them ?

I tried:

```
const worker = createWorker({
    logger: m => { }
});
```

Also

```
await worker.setParameters({
    debug_file: '/dev/null',
});
```

Also tried rewriting global `console.log` and `process.stdout`, still no luck with getting rid of this log message.

Comment: you found any solution?